# understanding "bridge check" hop in packet flow in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, netfilter

According to ["Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking"](http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.svg)
drawing in Wikipedia [Netfilter article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter):

[image]

..one of the first hops in packet flow right after the traffic control
and queuing is **bridge check**. What exactly happens in **bridge check**? When does frame continue in `Link Layer` and when does it continue in `Network Layer`?

Answer (score 3):

When you add a network interface to a bridge (e.g. `brctl addif br0 eth0`), all received packets are diverted to the bridge.  If you try to set an IP address on the interface, it will be accepted, but you won't be able to use it to receive any packets - this is a common pitfall.  In the source code, the bridge sets an `rx_handler` on the interface, and consumes every packet.

This is what is meant by the bridge check in this diagram.  The choice is simply based on whether the network interface belongs to a bridge.

Comment: IF a layer2 broadcast packet arrives, but at layer 3 the IP destination is of the IP of the bridge interface, will the bridge interface receive this traffic ?

Comment: "the bridge sets an rx_handler on the interface, and consumes every packet" preventing any layer 3 processing from occurring at all.