# Packet flow in linux NAT enabled on bridge IP assigned interfaces

Tags: networking, bridge, nat

On My Linux machine, I have following configuration:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether bc:e6:7c:51:20:6b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
br0.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether bc:e6:7c:51:20:6b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
br0.2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 20.20.20.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 20.20.20.255
    ether bc:e6:7c:4d:8f:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether bc:e6:7c:51:20:6b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether bc:e6:7c:51:3a:b0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
```

```shellsession
/ # brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.bce67c51206b       no              eth0
                                                        eth1
```

There are 2 layer 3 interfaces `br0.1` and `br0.2` created on top of bridge. This is a non typical NAT configuration where `br0.2` is serving DHCP to client on LAN side connected via `eth1`. It has static IP of 20.20.20.1 and `br0.1` is connected as a wan port via `eth0` and getting IP from DHCP via `eth0`.

There is also a masquerade rule in postrouting chain

```
table ip haswell-nat {
        chain haswell-postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
                ip saddr 20.20.20.0/24 masquerade
        }
}
```

- NAT is happening as when I ping from client (20.20.20.2) to default gateway 192.168.0.10.
- I see packet coming from 192.168.0.103.

I am wondering how this ping packet gets masqueraded given that both `eth0` and `eth1` are under bridge interface. Usually `eth0` and `eth1` would be separate interfaces and not under any bridge.

If they are under the bridge, shouldn't the packet simply get forwarded to the other interfaces without hiting the iptable rule, since it is on the IP layer ?

Edit:
The bridge is vlan aware:

```
/ # bridge vlan show
port              vlan-id
eth0              1 PVID Egress Untagged
                  2
                  15
br0               1
                  2
                  15
eth1              1 PVID Egress Untagged
```

Comment: In linux abc.x is a vlan interface where x is the vlan id, and here they also have an IP address which should make them a Layer 3 interface ?

Comment: example of layer 3 interfaces: tun/tap in tun mode, ipip, wireguard, ...

Comment: The interfaces are under bridge, so where does NAT even come to picture. It should just forward the frames from eth1 to eth0 and vice versa. Another strange thing I observed, If I remove the "ip saddr" rule, it still converts source IP to 192.168.0.103.

Comment: I noticed that you fixed your title but not some content: "There are 2 layer 3 interfaces br0.1 and br0.2 created on top of bridge." is wrong. These are layer 2 interfaces (they are Ethernet interfaces so that's layer 2).

Answer (score 1):

OP didn't give all the details but:

> br0.1 is connected as a wan port via eth0 and getting IP from DHCP via eth0

> br0.2 is serving DHCP to client on LAN side connected via eth1

I can only assume *eth0* and *eth1* receive VLAN-tagged traffic from external equipment such as a switch with VLANs configured on its ports, this tagged traffic is transparently bridged by *br0* (which is not configured to be VLAN-aware or OP would have described it).

This VLAN-tagged traffic gets filtered by the switch so doesn't leak "on the other side".

This traffic *also* reaches the bridge's self interface: the one intended to participate in *routing*. With VLAN sub interfaces on top of it, this allows to have multiple interfaces participating in routing from received traffic: this becomes a router with two interfaces *br0.1* and *br0.2* participating in routing ( *br0* would also participate but it's not configured with an IP address so doesn't. The possible interactions with ARP are negligible).

Even if my assumptions are a bit off, this doesn't matter with regard to how *routing* rather than *bridging* will happen.

---

*eth0* and *eth1* are not participating in routing: they are only bridge ports. Likewise, *br0* doesn't participate in routing since there's no address on it and I can assume no route either was added that would use it.

The remaining interfaces involved in routing are:

- br0.1 : WAN
- br0.2 : LAN

I can assume routes (`ip route`) are similar to this:

```shell
# ip route
default via 192.168.0.10 dev br0.1 
20.20.20.0/24 dev br0.2 proto kernel scope link src 20.20.20.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0.1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.103
```

From now on, one can disregard the involvement of a bridge or of bridge ports: if the traffic does reach *br0.1* or *br0.2* then this becomes *routed* IP packets (over Ethernet-like interfaces), not *bridged* frames.

Netfilter's *conntrack* (and NAT) works with IP addresses and *nftables* can select behavior by interface. Here the ruleset doesn't involve interface names but only addresses: whenever a packet with IP source in 20.20.20.0/24 is masqueraded in nat/postrouting.

The two different cases are:

- locally initiated flows on the system using the non-default source address of 20.20.20.1 are NAT-ed.
- routed packets coming from 20.20.20.0/24 are NAT-ed

Had the request been from client 20.20.20.2 to for example an other client 20.20.20.3, then this time, the traffic would have been *bridged* rather than *routed*: (except for an ARP broadcast) it would never have reached *br0*, *br0.1* or *br0.2* and no routing would have happened. The *nftables* IP hook would not have been used at all and no NAT would have happened (unless the kernel module [`br_netfilter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst#n2778) [is loaded](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) which gets [NAT probably working for bridged traffic](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7) too. This should never be needed or used with *nftables*.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info: My question is also related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281108/understanding-bridge-check-hop-in-packet-flow-in-linux-kernel

Comment: So, if a bridge interface has an IP address assigned, normal bridging will not happen and it will reach the network layer right ?

Comment: I didn't say what you wrote in your comment. I said that a Linux bridge has only one "side" that can participate in routing: the bridge interface itself. All bridge ports are barred from routing. Attempting to do routing by adding IP addresses and thus probably automatic LAN routes to bridge ports would just disrupt correct routing. Of course bridging still happens in a bridge: that's its role.

Comment: It looks like you already got the same answer in your linked question, except that I chose my vocabulary carefully: I just say "bridge port" and not anymore "interface" to avoid confusion when talking about an interface that was set as bridge port. br0 is not a bridge port: it's the part of the bridge itself that is available to the routing stack (the green layer).

Comment: Does setting bridge-nf-call-iptables proc entry also affect this scenario, that the masquerading rule will be hit for bridged packets as well. Because, in my setup, it is set to 1

Comment: @RootPhoenix bridge-nf-call-iptables might possibly affect this scenario. But I don't know how it behaves with *also* VLAN-tagged frames. Then there's also net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged and net.bridge.bridge-nf-pass-vlan-input-dev to consider. using br_netfilter (and thus Docker and Kubernetes at the same time as a special network setup) should be avoided whenever possible. Consider nftables with kernel >= 5.3 which can do the job in the bridge family directly. Anyway, you'll have to update your question first to clarify all the things that I'm not sure in my answer.